# a program that it will change variable name every time function runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
u1 = 'value1'
u2 = 'value2'
u3 = 'value3'
i = 1

while i < 10:

       function()
    
       m = u1   

#here I want that the next time script will run with m = u2
```

Comment: And what about the 4th time? you have 3 variables and 10 iterations of the loop.

Comment: Make `u` a `dictionary` with 1, 2, 3 as `keys` and 'value1' etc. as `values`, and assign `m=u[i]`

Comment: Here I took 3 variables as an example. As function ends I want m = u2 and rerun function and then m = u3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for-loop if you can have your variables in a list. Something like this:

```py
variables_list = ['u1', 'u2']

def your_function(var_name):
     pass   # or your own logic

for var in variables_list:  # You can iterate through the elements
                            # of a list using for...in....
    your_function(var)
```